# geojson contents can not be visualised

Tags: json, angular, geojson

in my code i have generated the below posted `geojson` output. however, when i tried to visualise its contents in the followin website [https://geojson.io/](https://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0) i do not get any visual output.
please let me know correct the below posted `geojson`.

**geojson**:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66079022243348,51.140794993202],[6.66079005460558,51.1407983122385],[6.66081135709435,51.1407987385067],[6.66080873391236,51.1407981018504],[6.66079022243348,51.140794993202]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.647782903636197", "ETRa_soil": "0.0400227641046727", "ETRc_soil": "7.65935710118916", "PECgw": "4168.4374316502"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[6.66049410863497,51.1409985164652],[6.66049411228518,51.1409984442868],[6.66049407370026,51.1409984842113],[6.66049410863497,51.1409985164652]]],[[[6.66049457721976,51.14098925077],[6.66049543865696,51.1409722168828],[6.66044876649505,51.1409712828309],[6.66049457721976,51.14098925077]]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.177577611929162", "ETRa_soil": "0.0934526392159067", "ETRc_soil": "17.8845002791712", "PECgw": "9733.24776807721"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[6.66064910499184,51.1407591404876],[6.66064726863041,51.1407954549773],[6.66068859193834,51.1407962819142],[6.66065225500977,51.1407598944706],[6.66064910499184,51.1407591404876]]],[[[6.66077024294677,51.1407979158214],[6.66079009430318,51.1407983130556],[6.66079026183779,51.1407949998192],[6.66078137299918,51.1407935071077],[6.66077024294677,51.1407979158214]]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.28852769378483", "ETRa_soil": "0.0808452757479024", "ETRc_soil": "15.4717658999718", "PECgw": "8420.16989926723"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66043337245854,51.1408810874443],[6.66049997989679,51.1408824204657],[6.6605039746486,51.1408034284145],[6.66049858662808,51.140809049721],[6.66049847250583,51.1408012466777],[6.66049259787335,51.1408071550042],[6.66047598480274,51.1408275084349],[6.66046929349543,51.1408382571074],[6.66046911886301,51.1408388831836],[6.66046910890004,51.1408398037521],[6.66045458061045,51.1408549610759],[6.66043750722066,51.1408759348598],[6.66043337245854,51.1408810874443]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.95875163585475", "ETRa_soil": "0.00468709090198103", "ETRc_soil": "0.896992094052197", "PECgw": "488.168311170785"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66078551152349,51.1408881565072],[6.66078106877664,51.1409760174891],[6.66079877671441,51.1409582633473],[6.66086141144714,51.1408929620131],[6.66086410806563,51.1408896813464],[6.66078555930881,51.1408881095832],[6.66078551152349,51.1408881565072]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.991780933222734", "ETRa_soil": "0.000933940385583422", "ETRc_soil": "0.178732855774211", "PECgw": "97.2714441215027"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66050693190458,51.1407926465578],[6.660647308328,51.1407954557945],[6.66064914425548,51.1407591498856],[6.66055958831034,51.1407377138789],[6.66055364416397,51.1407365156578],[6.66055029102368,51.1407377976343],[6.6605477857488,51.1407392764561],[6.6605423532381,51.1407449238168],[6.66052985094832,51.1407603229531],[6.66050511836349,51.1407913964812],[6.66050693190458,51.1407926465578]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.987662605743044", "ETRa_soil": "0.00140190985931724", "ETRc_soil": "0.268290521067109", "PECgw": "146.011242953987"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66044883557746,51.1409713099265],[6.66049543739402,51.1409722425705],[6.66049998115972,51.1408823947779],[6.66043339276621,51.1408810621376],[6.66042514768543,51.1408913368421],[6.66040117907167,51.1409214363123],[6.66038337074439,51.1409456331738],[6.66044883557746,51.1409713099265]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.884982556662815", "ETRa_soil": "0.0130695416268265", "ETRc_soil": "2.50118373151128", "PECgw": "1361.21449256459"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66079005586835,51.1407982865507],[6.66078739343633,51.1408509398627],[6.66079862849856,51.1408537515861],[6.66083550854172,51.14084867975],[6.66083544122551,51.1408552077224],[6.66083994787324,51.1408619381473],[6.66081827230877,51.1408582818435],[6.66080951847558,51.1408645822662],[6.66078553364671,51.1408881347828],[6.6608640872722,51.1408897066434],[6.66087268473994,51.1408792470862],[6.6608755937829,51.1408754379299],[6.66087625948697,51.1408743642673],[6.66087913518067,51.1408732603238],[6.66088228444444,51.1408703553614],[6.66089792427524,51.1408551089074],[6.66089838909667,51.1408543986984],[6.66086119388093,51.1408463694017],[6.66084373055219,51.1408475490385],[6.66084829866778,51.1408469208198],[6.66086689496409,51.1408297548763],[6.66087267925071,51.1408199773584],[6.66087271360274,51.1408164704356],[6.66085760189237,51.140809962283],[6.66081124163047,51.1407987104832],[6.66079005586835,51.1407982865507]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.71412562714461", "ETRa_soil": "0.0324841772488655", "ETRc_soil": "6.21665992475359", "PECgw": "3383.28107539983"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[6.66063818546419,51.1409750735191],[6.66063601279755,51.1410180379841],[6.66065184757205,51.1410167513147],[6.66067158288883,51.1410138185135],[6.66068332505489,51.1410049696782],[6.66070780973692,51.1409816258827],[6.66071018823114,51.1409765143888],[6.66063818546419,51.1409750735191]]],[[[6.66077919587118,51.1409778952804],[6.66075474410624,51.140977405988],[6.66075649787208,51.1409800818877],[6.66076946524305,51.1409837590433],[6.6607757339826,51.1409813661995],[6.66077919587118,51.1409778952804]]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.253302540397098", "ETRa_soil": "0.0848479434751155", "ETRc_soil": "16.2377764983391", "PECgw": "8837.05439872202"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66049539895922,51.1409722160655],[6.66049453825359,51.1409892354866],[6.66049790592691,51.1409905563584],[6.66050254127054,51.140989925155],[6.66049799619706,51.1409944255302],[6.66049407370026,51.1409984842113],[6.66051538223784,51.141018157541],[6.66052910659558,51.1410238285246],[6.66054704819211,51.1410252668449],[6.66063605270061,51.1410180347417],[6.66063822516193,51.1409750743363],[6.66049539895922,51.1409722160655]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.691031936305826", "ETRa_soil": "0.0351083353328678", "ETRc_soil": "6.71885821877395", "PECgw": "3656.59150331816"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[6.66064272769041,51.1408852514052],[6.66063818420133,51.1409750992069],[6.66071017637666,51.1409765398646],[6.66071390500723,51.1409685268629],[6.66071055126937,51.1409439099285],[6.66072623612857,51.140919757016],[6.66071856834969,51.1409093255937],[6.66073228793538,51.1409103446131],[6.6607385396446,51.1408969789063],[6.66073714773113,51.1408962315432],[6.66073371339569,51.1408975378437],[6.66073857855034,51.1408933821359],[6.66073861291278,51.1408898752133],[6.6607385400128,51.140887168723],[6.66064272769041,51.1408852514052]],[[6.6607140598979,51.1409031921924],[6.66071925407906,51.140903108498],[6.66071518625459,51.1409047245139],[6.6607140598979,51.1409031921924]]],[[[6.66075476118234,51.1409774320427],[6.66077917072688,51.1409779204903],[6.66078111063798,51.1409759755185],[6.66078555333878,51.1408881154456],[6.66075054580207,51.1409224919393],[6.66074440965898,51.1409363995916],[6.66074370659916,51.1409389937458],[6.6607444014066,51.1409506996834],[6.66074604147812,51.140963503801],[6.66075052501954,51.1409709684949],[6.66075476118234,51.1409774320427]]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.762576290120202", "ETRa_soil": "0.0269786822714604", "ETRc_soil": "5.16304573807562", "PECgw": "2809.87461892527"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[6.66064726989326,51.1407954292895],[6.66064272642756,51.1408852770929],[6.66073854070576,51.1408871944499],[6.66073851353583,51.140886185737],[6.6607323166692,51.1408730206179],[6.66072633929129,51.1408639970718],[6.66072044311788,51.1408590223929],[6.66069250955009,51.1408382566758],[6.66070162877013,51.1408352618304],[6.66070755137455,51.1408255770271],[6.6607075948258,51.1408218904088],[6.66070763373369,51.1408182936384],[6.660701651824,51.140809359939],[6.66068856573734,51.1407962556768],[6.66064726989326,51.1407954292895]]],[[[6.66078553362401,51.140888134805],[6.66078555237702,51.1408881351803],[6.6607855533768,51.1408881154083],[6.66078553362401,51.140888134805]]],[[[6.6607874326787,51.1408509496837],[6.66079009556595,51.1407982873678],[6.66077030473932,51.1407978913448],[6.66076970161208,51.1407981302489],[6.6607632693411,51.140803757614],[6.66075661643472,51.1408165756616],[6.6607557063733,51.1408260909554],[6.6607631205245,51.1408406295129],[6.66076956074425,51.1408461547086],[6.66078691024833,51.1408508189385],[6.6607874326787,51.1408509496837]]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.578273065296824", "ETRa_soil": "0.0479212332350216", "ETRc_soil": "9.17092675349607", "PECgw": "4991.076125209"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66050393269623,51.1408034721833],[6.66049994019913,51.1408824196485],[6.66064276612522,51.1408852779101],[6.66064730959085,51.1407954301067],[6.66050689348607,51.1407926200758],[6.66052970983289,51.1408083474096],[6.66053340789023,51.1408106991555],[6.66053071998254,51.1408106734032],[6.66051715086203,51.1408022500543],[6.66050733224076,51.1408013340471],[6.66050499250535,51.1408023664872],[6.66050393269623,51.1408034721833]],[[6.66054102438944,51.1408274780477],[6.66055347300262,51.1408331963643],[6.66055543626421,51.1408337241709],[6.66054747174923,51.1408359543041],[6.66054741919786,51.1408398206177],[6.66054875587623,51.1408478722288],[6.66054102438944,51.1408274780477]],[[6.66055928654052,51.1408326460601],[6.66055931325502,51.1408307949571],[6.66055935895622,51.1408271998522],[6.66056613056901,51.1408288627964],[6.66057106131433,51.1408293490214],[6.66055928654052,51.1408326460601]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.983466593572459", "ETRa_soil": "0.00187870671846284", "ETRc_soil": "0.359537527380078", "PECgw": "195.670428655349"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66049994146206,51.1408823939607],[6.66049539769628,51.1409722417533],[6.66063822389907,51.1409751000241],[6.66064276738808,51.1408852522223],[6.66049994146206,51.1408823939607]],[[6.6605684300883,51.1409345855812],[6.66057302348829,51.1409272138277],[6.66057303103794,51.1409265161076],[6.66057526186566,51.1409300185161],[6.66057298002594,51.1409309004456],[6.6605684300883,51.1409345855812]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.99896577029807", "ETRa_soil": "0.000117520506010963", "ETRc_soil": "0.0224904886603103", "PECgw": "12.2399561150095"}}]}
```

**attempts to solve this issue**
i re-formatted it to appear as follows but still cant not see its contents in the above mentioned link

```
    {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66079022243348,51.140794993202],[6.66079005460558,51.1407983122385],[6.66081135709435,51.1407987385067],[6.66080873391236,51.1407981018504],[6.66079022243348,51.140794993202]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.647782903636197', 'ETRa_soil': '0.0400227641046727', 'ETRc_soil': '7.65935710118916', 'PECgw': '4168.4374316502'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[6.66049410863497,51.1409985164652],[6.66049411228518,51.1409984442868],[6.66049407370026,51.1409984842113],[6.66049410863497,51.1409985164652]]],[[[6.66049457721976,51.14098925077],[6.66049543865696,51.1409722168828],[6.66044876649505,51.1409712828309],[6.66049457721976,51.14098925077]]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.177577611929162', 'ETRa_soil': '0.0934526392159067', 'ETRc_soil': '17.8845002791712', 'PECgw': '9733.24776807721'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[6.66064910499184,51.1407591404876],[6.66064726863041,51.1407954549773],[6.66068859193834,51.1407962819142],[6.66065225500977,51.1407598944706],[6.66064910499184,51.1407591404876]]],[[[6.66077024294677,51.1407979158214],[6.66079009430318,51.1407983130556],[6.66079026183779,51.1407949998192],[6.66078137299918,51.1407935071077],[6.66077024294677,51.1407979158214]]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.28852769378483', 'ETRa_soil': '0.0808452757479024', 'ETRc_soil': '15.4717658999718', 'PECgw': '8420.16989926723'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66043337245854,51.1408810874443],[6.66049997989679,51.1408824204657],[6.6605039746486,51.1408034284145],[6.66049858662808,51.140809049721],[6.66049847250583,51.1408012466777],[6.66049259787335,51.1408071550042],[6.66047598480274,51.1408275084349],[6.66046929349543,51.1408382571074],[6.66046911886301,51.1408388831836],[6.66046910890004,51.1408398037521],[6.66045458061045,51.1408549610759],[6.66043750722066,51.1408759348598],[6.66043337245854,51.1408810874443]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.95875163585475', 'ETRa_soil': '0.00468709090198103', 'ETRc_soil': '0.896992094052197', 'PECgw': '488.168311170785'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66078551152349,51.1408881565072],[6.66078106877664,51.1409760174891],[6.66079877671441,51.1409582633473],[6.66086141144714,51.1408929620131],[6.66086410806563,51.1408896813464],[6.66078555930881,51.1408881095832],[6.66078551152349,51.1408881565072]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.991780933222734', 'ETRa_soil': '0.000933940385583422', 'ETRc_soil': '0.178732855774211', 'PECgw': '97.2714441215027'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66050693190458,51.1407926465578],[6.660647308328,51.1407954557945],[6.66064914425548,51.1407591498856],[6.66055958831034,51.1407377138789],[6.66055364416397,51.1407365156578],[6.66055029102368,51.1407377976343],[6.6605477857488,51.1407392764561],[6.6605423532381,51.1407449238168],[6.66052985094832,51.1407603229531],[6.66050511836349,51.1407913964812],[6.66050693190458,51.1407926465578]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.987662605743044', 'ETRa_soil': '0.00140190985931724', 'ETRc_soil': '0.268290521067109', 'PECgw': '146.011242953987'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66044883557746,51.1409713099265],[6.66049543739402,51.1409722425705],[6.66049998115972,51.1408823947779],[6.66043339276621,51.1408810621376],[6.66042514768543,51.1408913368421],[6.66040117907167,51.1409214363123],[6.66038337074439,51.1409456331738],[6.66044883557746,51.1409713099265]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.884982556662815', 'ETRa_soil': '0.0130695416268265', 'ETRc_soil': '2.50118373151128', 'PECgw': '1361.21449256459'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66079005586835,51.1407982865507],[6.66078739343633,51.1408509398627],[6.66079862849856,51.1408537515861],[6.66083550854172,51.14084867975],[6.66083544122551,51.1408552077224],[6.66083994787324,51.1408619381473],[6.66081827230877,51.1408582818435],[6.66080951847558,51.1408645822662],[6.66078553364671,51.1408881347828],[6.6608640872722,51.1408897066434],[6.66087268473994,51.1408792470862],[6.6608755937829,51.1408754379299],[6.66087625948697,51.1408743642673],[6.66087913518067,51.1408732603238],[6.66088228444444,51.1408703553614],[6.66089792427524,51.1408551089074],[6.66089838909667,51.1408543986984],[6.66086119388093,51.1408463694017],[6.66084373055219,51.1408475490385],[6.66084829866778,51.1408469208198],[6.66086689496409,51.1408297548763],[6.66087267925071,51.1408199773584],[6.66087271360274,51.1408164704356],[6.66085760189237,51.140809962283],[6.66081124163047,51.1407987104832],[6.66079005586835,51.1407982865507]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.71412562714461', 'ETRa_soil': '0.0324841772488655', 'ETRc_soil': '6.21665992475359', 'PECgw': '3383.28107539983'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[6.66063818546419,51.1409750735191],[6.66063601279755,51.1410180379841],[6.66065184757205,51.1410167513147],[6.66067158288883,51.1410138185135],[6.66068332505489,51.1410049696782],[6.66070780973692,51.1409816258827],[6.66071018823114,51.1409765143888],[6.66063818546419,51.1409750735191]]],[[[6.66077919587118,51.1409778952804],[6.66075474410624,51.140977405988],[6.66075649787208,51.1409800818877],[6.66076946524305,51.1409837590433],[6.6607757339826,51.1409813661995],[6.66077919587118,51.1409778952804]]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.253302540397098', 'ETRa_soil': '0.0848479434751155', 'ETRc_soil': '16.2377764983391', 'PECgw': '8837.05439872202'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66049539895922,51.1409722160655],[6.66049453825359,51.1409892354866],[6.66049790592691,51.1409905563584],[6.66050254127054,51.140989925155],[6.66049799619706,51.1409944255302],[6.66049407370026,51.1409984842113],[6.66051538223784,51.141018157541],[6.66052910659558,51.1410238285246],[6.66054704819211,51.1410252668449],[6.66063605270061,51.1410180347417],[6.66063822516193,51.1409750743363],[6.66049539895922,51.1409722160655]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.691031936305826', 'ETRa_soil': '0.0351083353328678', 'ETRc_soil': '6.71885821877395', 'PECgw': '3656.59150331816'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[6.66064272769041,51.1408852514052],[6.66063818420133,51.1409750992069],[6.66071017637666,51.1409765398646],[6.66071390500723,51.1409685268629],[6.66071055126937,51.1409439099285],[6.66072623612857,51.140919757016],[6.66071856834969,51.1409093255937],[6.66073228793538,51.1409103446131],[6.6607385396446,51.1408969789063],[6.66073714773113,51.1408962315432],[6.66073371339569,51.1408975378437],[6.66073857855034,51.1408933821359],[6.66073861291278,51.1408898752133],[6.6607385400128,51.140887168723],[6.66064272769041,51.1408852514052]],[[6.6607140598979,51.1409031921924],[6.66071925407906,51.140903108498],[6.66071518625459,51.1409047245139],[6.6607140598979,51.1409031921924]]],[[[6.66075476118234,51.1409774320427],[6.66077917072688,51.1409779204903],[6.66078111063798,51.1409759755185],[6.66078555333878,51.1408881154456],[6.66075054580207,51.1409224919393],[6.66074440965898,51.1409363995916],[6.66074370659916,51.1409389937458],[6.6607444014066,51.1409506996834],[6.66074604147812,51.140963503801],[6.66075052501954,51.1409709684949],[6.66075476118234,51.1409774320427]]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.762576290120202', 'ETRa_soil': '0.0269786822714604', 'ETRc_soil': '5.16304573807562', 'PECgw': '2809.87461892527'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[6.66064726989326,51.1407954292895],[6.66064272642756,51.1408852770929],[6.66073854070576,51.1408871944499],[6.66073851353583,51.140886185737],[6.6607323166692,51.1408730206179],[6.66072633929129,51.1408639970718],[6.66072044311788,51.1408590223929],[6.66069250955009,51.1408382566758],[6.66070162877013,51.1408352618304],[6.66070755137455,51.1408255770271],[6.6607075948258,51.1408218904088],[6.66070763373369,51.1408182936384],[6.660701651824,51.140809359939],[6.66068856573734,51.1407962556768],[6.66064726989326,51.1407954292895]]],[[[6.66078553362401,51.140888134805],[6.66078555237702,51.1408881351803],[6.6607855533768,51.1408881154083],[6.66078553362401,51.140888134805]]],[[[6.6607874326787,51.1408509496837],[6.66079009556595,51.1407982873678],[6.66077030473932,51.1407978913448],[6.66076970161208,51.1407981302489],[6.6607632693411,51.140803757614],[6.66075661643472,51.1408165756616],[6.6607557063733,51.1408260909554],[6.6607631205245,51.1408406295129],[6.66076956074425,51.1408461547086],[6.66078691024833,51.1408508189385],[6.6607874326787,51.1408509496837]]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.578273065296824', 'ETRa_soil': '0.0479212332350216', 'ETRc_soil': '9.17092675349607', 'PECgw': '4991.076125209'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66050393269623,51.1408034721833],[6.66049994019913,51.1408824196485],[6.66064276612522,51.1408852779101],[6.66064730959085,51.1407954301067],[6.66050689348607,51.1407926200758],[6.66052970983289,51.1408083474096],[6.66053340789023,51.1408106991555],[6.66053071998254,51.1408106734032],[6.66051715086203,51.1408022500543],[6.66050733224076,51.1408013340471],[6.66050499250535,51.1408023664872],[6.66050393269623,51.1408034721833]],[[6.66054102438944,51.1408274780477],[6.66055347300262,51.1408331963643],[6.66055543626421,51.1408337241709],[6.66054747174923,51.1408359543041],[6.66054741919786,51.1408398206177],[6.66054875587623,51.1408478722288],[6.66054102438944,51.1408274780477]],[[6.66055928654052,51.1408326460601],[6.66055931325502,51.1408307949571],[6.66055935895622,51.1408271998522],[6.66056613056901,51.1408288627964],[6.66057106131433,51.1408293490214],[6.66055928654052,51.1408326460601]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.983466593572459', 'ETRa_soil': '0.00187870671846284', 'ETRc_soil': '0.359537527380078', 'PECgw': '195.670428655349'}}, {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66049994146206,51.1408823939607],[6.66049539769628,51.1409722417533],[6.66063822389907,51.1409751000241],[6.66064276738808,51.1408852522223],[6.66049994146206,51.1408823939607]],[[6.6605684300883,51.1409345855812],[6.66057302348829,51.1409272138277],[6.66057303103794,51.1409265161076],[6.66057526186566,51.1409300185161],[6.66057298002594,51.1409309004456],[6.6605684300883,51.1409345855812]]]}', 'properties': {'AreaOfCoverage': '0.99896577029807', 'ETRa_soil': '0.000117520506010963', 'ETRc_soil': '0.0224904886603103', 'PECgw': '12.2399561150095'}}]}
```

Comment: It's just invalid JSON. Use tools like jsoneditoronline.org or jsonlint.com to check the validity. For example this doesn't make sense: `...'geometry': '{"type":"Polygon",...`. You don't want the `{}` block inside any quotation marks.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen i used the link you provided to test both of the above mentioned geojson formate. Despit the first one was successful, it still shows no results in the link i mentioned in my question above...would you please ´help me to fix it

Comment: Neither is successfull. Both JSON are invalid. Remove the quotation marks around the `{...}` blocks. Jsonlint seems like the more useful tool in this case as it shows more detailed errors.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen i used the following sample:{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[6.66079022243348,51.140794993202],[6.66079005460558,51.1407983122385],[6.66081135709435,51.1407987385067],[6.66080873391236,51.1407981018504],[6.66079022243348,51.140794993202]]]}", "properties": {"AreaOfCoverage": "0.647782903636197", "ETRa_soil": "0.0400227641046727", "ETRc_soil": "7.65935710118916", "PECgw": "4168.4374316502"}}]}
i entered it in jsonlint and itis valid but does not show any results in  https://geojson.io/

Comment: In the geojson.io tool you can see a red square at the left side of the JSON pointing that there's an error. It's valid JSON, but doesn't meet the GeoJSON specification. Just hover your mouse on the red square and a more detailed error message pops up. And you still have the quotation marks around the `{...}` block which makes them strings instead of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The data must be valid JSON and it also needs to match the GeoJSON specification.

Here's a corrected version of your shorter example data:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.66079022243348,51.140794993202],[6.66079005460558,51.1407983122385],[6.66081135709435,51.1407987385067],[6.66080873391236,51.1407981018504],[6.66079022243348,51.140794993202]]]},
        "properties": {
            "AreaOfCoverage": "0.647782903636197",
            "ETRa_soil": "0.0400227641046727",
            "ETRc_soil": "7.65935710118916",
            "PECgw": "4168.4374316502"
        }
    }]
}
```

A major difference from the problematic data was the removal of the single/double quotes around the geometry object i.e. the {...} block as the quotes make it a string value instead of a JSON object.